# How to set winform start position at top right?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, startup

How to set `winform` start position at top right? I mean when user click (start) my winform application the winform will appear at the top right of the screen?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the Load event to change the position, the earliest you'll know the actual size of the window after user preferences and automatic scaling are applied:

```
Public Class Form1
    Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim scr = Screen.FromPoint(Me.Location)
        Me.Location = New Point(scr.WorkingArea.Right - Me.Width, scr.WorkingArea.Top)
        MyBase.OnLoad(e)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 3):

In form load even send the windows position to y=0 and x= Screen width - form width.

e.g.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.Location = new Point( Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Right - this.Width,0);
}
```

You can alternatively use "Screen.GetBounds(this).Right". This will give you the coordinates of screen which contain your form.

Comment: I couldn't comment on a related answer. Because I didn't have enough reputation. sorry for that.

"I'm struggling with Screen.GetBounds function. This function ask a pt point type parameter. What value should I put in? "

The point parameter is for different scenario. It is used in case you have multiple screens and you want to find the appropriate screen to be used based on a point coordinate. 
Primary screen parameter should be just enoguh for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Form.Location to set the location to a Point that represents the top left corner of the form.

So if you set this to 'Screenwidth - Formwidth' you can position the Form in the top right.
To get the screen width you can use the [Screen.Bounds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.bounds.aspx) property.

Comment: I'm struggling with Screen.GetBounds function. This function ask a pt point type parameter. What value should I put in?

Comment: I've added a documentation link

Answer (score 1):

Add the line of code in *frm.Designer.cs* file

```
this.Location = new Point(0,0);
```

Note:
Check if the location is already set in  frm.resX file you can change it there.
Or remove from *.resX* file and add the above line in *frm.Designer.cs*

Any way it will work.

Answer (score 1):

to show on the primary monitor if you have multi monitor useful for multi monitor setup

Start on Upper Right

```
Public Class Form1
    Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim scr = Screen.AllScreens(0)
        Me.Location = New Point(scr.WorkingArea.Right - Me.Width, scr.WorkingArea.Top)
        MyBase.OnLoad(e)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Start on Upper Left

```
Public Class Form1
    Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim scr = Screen.AllScreens(0)
        Me.Location = New Point(scr.WorkingArea.Right - Me.Width - scr.WorkingArea.Right + Me.Width, scr.WorkingArea.Top)
        MyBase.OnLoad(e)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Add This to your OnLoad Event

```
    Me.Location = New Point(1, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this in OnLoad Event of your Form

```
 private void dlgTTMSContract_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   int screenWidth = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size.Width;
   int formWidth = this.Width;
   this.Location = new Point(screenWidth - formWidth, 0);
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

It works fine for you:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Location = new Point(Screen.FromPoint(this.Location).WorkingArea.Right - this.Width, 0);
        }
```