# Powershell and .NET form object

Tags: .net, winforms, powershell

I need to create a basic "helpdesk style" tool that uses some powershell scripts.
I'm using .NET form object to create a window, but I can't set properly the Localtion attribute (and other attributes that need a Point object)

```
$form = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form;
$form.AutoSize = $true;
$form.minimumSize = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400, 300);
$form.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 10);
$form.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0;

$form.ShowDialog();
```

The window form appears, dimensions are correct, but position is wrong.
Am I missing something?

Comment: `$form.StartPosition = "manual"`

Answer (score 4):

You can change the location property in the Load event:

```
$handler_form_Load = {
    $form.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 10);
}

$form = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form;
$form.AutoSize = $true;
$form.minimumSize = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400, 300);
$form.add_Load($handler_form_Load)
$form.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0;

$form.ShowDialog();
```

Also, as you found @Lorenzo, set the StartPosition to [manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formstartposition.aspx) to honor the location property on load, so the event handler above isn't needed.

```
$form.StartPosition = "manual"
```

Comment: +1 - Supplemental link for further explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892090/how-to-set-winform-start-position-at-top-right

Comment: Thank you!
I found another easier solution, just setting `StartPosition` properly

`$form.StartPosition = "manual"`

Comment: Add that as an answer, it's probably more appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify a new object for the position or sizes. As added by Andy the `StartPostion` property is what you need to change to `Manual`. Then simply give the `Location` property a string value like `'x, y'`.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$Form               = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.AutoSize      = $true
$Form.minimumSize   = '800, 300'
$Form.StartPosition = 'Manual'
$Form.Location      = '500, 500'

$Form.ShowDialog()
```