# Winforms to start center (in terms of height) but to the left of the screen

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm trying to adapt @HansPasant's code from `vb.net` to `c#`. Also I want to adapt it so the `winForms` starts centered in terms of top-to-bottom but to the far left of the screen in terms of left-to-right:

`vb.net` from here [How to set winform start position at top right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892090/how-to-set-winform-start-position-at-top-right) :

```
Public Class Form1
    Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim scr = Screen.FromPoint(Me.Location)
        Me.Location = New Point(scr.WorkingArea.Right - Me.Width, scr.WorkingArea.Top)
        MyBase.OnLoad(e)
    End Sub
End Class
```

My current (bad) attempt:

```
private void scriptSurfer_Load(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    var scr = Screen.FromPoint(this.Location);
    this.Location = New Point(scr.WorkingArea.Left - this.Width, scr.WorkingArea.Top);
    this.OnLoad(e);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I have understood your question you need

> ```
> The LeftMost position of the Screen = 0
> Vertical Centering = (Screen.Height - form.Height) / 2
> ```

```
this.Location = new Point(0, (scr.WorkingArea.Height - this.Height) / 2);
```

and do not forget

> ```
> Form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
> ```

As noted below in comments, the best point in which execute this code is inside the override of the OnLoad method albeit a Load event should work just fine in 99% of the situations. Also using the `Screen.WorkingArea.Left` property to position the form on the left side of the screen could be better instead of a fixed leftmost position. This could avoid edge cases where the leftmost available position is not at zero coordinates.

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    var scr = Screen.PrimaryScreen;
    this.Location = new Point(scr.WorkingArea.Left, 
                             (scr.WorkingArea.Height - this.Height) / 2);
    base.OnLoad(e);
}
```

Comment: thanks steve...what about the signature?: this is closer than in my question: `protected override void OnLoad(object sender,EventArgs e)` but still not quite there

Comment: I think you coud go with the Form_Load event without problems

Comment: ok - good - Form_Load event  seems fine - this line of code is not required:  `this.OnLoad(e);`

Comment: `scr.WorkingArea.Left` is correct.  It won't be `0` if anything is docked to the **left** side of the screen...

Comment: Form_Load will work fine but OnLoad is preferred is many situations. Form_Load is still there for legacy reasons. If you're interested in more, check these out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670806/form-load-event-or-override-onload https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521322/what-setup-code-should-go-in-form-constructors-versus-form-load-event

Comment: @Saragis of course what Hans Passant says is completely true. Overriding OnLoad is better but I have no context to understand if this is an issue here.

Comment: Your vertical centering also needs a slight tweak to handle those pesky "edge" cases.  If anything is docked to the top (TaskBar and/or third-party AppBars), then as with the .Left value, the .Top value will not be zero.  With that in mind, instead of `(scr.WorkingArea.Height - this.Height) / 2`, you'd use `scr.WorkingArea.Top + (scr.WorkingArea.Height - this.Height) / 2`.